# Bootstrap - How to make the image responsive to some breakpoints?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am new to Bootstrap and this is my first experience. The header of my website is like the following image

[image]

I want this image to be responsive on medium devices size and larger but on smaller devices I want it to be cropped from center and be like this

[image]

I tried to do it but I failed. How can I do this?

---

This is my code, it works but it doesn't look very nice

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col" id="header-image">
      <img src="images/head.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="z-index: -1; visibility: hidden">
    </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #header image{
    background-position: center !important;
    background-size: auto 100% !important;
    height: 217px;
  }
}
#header #header-image{
   background-image: url("images/head.jpg");
   background-size: 100% auto ;
   background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: Addin a live view of your code, will help you get a usefull answer

Comment: I suggest using background image instead of a normal one

Comment: You can use media queries

Comment: @JonathanHamel I can't do this using pure Bootstrap?

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO the website is in localhost

Comment: @Drupalist bootstrap uses media queries behind the scenes. You can always use media queries to change the size of any dom element. You can also use percentages relative sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Use `object-fit:cover` on your image. It crops the image from sides and maintains its ratio. Works for responsive too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS media rules:
[CSS media Rules](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: This should really be a comment.